# how to create FormArray inside another array in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is my sample json array

`[ { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "city": "chennai", "street": "sivan koiil street", "pin": "600024","data":[{"company":"xyz","address":"yyy"}] },
]`

I tried  to create array inside another **array in app.component.ts** file. while i am checking in console i am not getting. Please help me how to create. Below is my source code URL
[CODE URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-formgroup2)

Below is my  Code

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms'

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `

<select *ngFor="let res of list">
<option>None</option>
<option>{{res.firstname}}</option>
</select>

<form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onMy(myForm.value)">


<ng-container formArrayName="users">
<div *ngFor="let user of myForm.controls.users.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
<input formControlName="firstname">
<input formControlName="lastname">

<textarea rows="15" cols="25" formControlName="street">    
</textarea>

</div>

</ng-container>
<button type="submit">Add</button>

</form>  

<pre>Form values: {{myForm.value | json}}</pre>


`,
styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  users = [ { "firstname": "ramu", "lastname": "mothukuri", "city": "chennai", "street": "sivan koiil street", "pin": "600024","data":[{"company":"xyz","address":"yyy"}] },
]
  list=[{"firstname":"ramu"},{"firstname":"ravi"}];
  myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      users: this.fb.array([]),data:this.fb.array([])
    });

    let formArr = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.users;
    this.users.forEach(user => {
      formArr.push(fb.group({
        firstname: user.firstname,
        lastname: user.lastname,
        street:user.street
      }));
    });
  }

  onMy(form) {
    console.log(form);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: post your code here instead of sharing it as a URL

Comment: sure Niladri, I have added

Comment: the default value of users is a Formarray , if you log it you should get `users` array with user properties as object

Comment: Yes i got users array object but inside data array is there i need to create formarray for that one, can you help me

Comment: can you update your question with this detail , it's not clear

Comment: I have uploaded screen shot, it's very clear i want to push data array inside users array. I am unable to add "data" array inside users array. that is my problem